# In XAML, what helpers:EnumHelper.Enum attribute means?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

In the following code snippet:

```
<ItemsControl helpers:EnumHelper.Enum="order:TShirtSizeEnum" ... >
...
</ItemsControl>
```

what helpers:EnumHelper.Enum attribute means?

Next is implementation of EnumHelper class

```
public class EnumHelper : DependencyObject
{
    public static Type GetEnum(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Type)obj.GetValue(EnumProperty);
    }

    public static void SetEnum(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(EnumProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Enum.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EnumProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Enum", typeof(Type), typeof(EnumHelper), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnEnumChanged));

    private static void OnEnumChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = sender as ItemsControl;

        if (control != null)
        {
            if (e.NewValue != null && e.NewValue as Type != null)
            {
                var _enum = Enum.GetValues(e.NewValue as Type);
                control.ItemsSource = _enum;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please also post the content of the class call EnumHelper in the namespace helpers declares in the top of that xaml. There should be something like `xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace: (....)"` go check that namespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably an [attached property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx). What it does depends on what `helpers` refers to (as it's probably not part of .NET i cannot tell you anything about it, but i would guess it uses reflection to get the enum values and sets them as `ItemsSource`).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it means the following: find class `EnumHelper` in namespace referenced above as `helpers`. This class defines an attached property `Enum`. Set the value of attached property for this object to ...